# convert a list of pairs with a fixed suffix to a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a big list like the below one:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'sth1', 'sth2', 'sth2_suffix', 'sth1_suffix', 'name2_suffix', 'name1_suffix']
```

and I want to make a dictionary of it like this:

```
my_dict = {'name1': 'name1_suffix', 
           'name2': 'name2_suffix', 
           'sth1': 'sth1_suffix', 
           'sth2': 'sth2_suffix'}
```

This means there are two types of elements: regular simple ones and the other ones with a fixed suffix that I want as keys or values.

Comment: What if they are not in pairs? If they always are, why can't you just ignore the `_suffix` ones and just add a pair for each item you find? i.e. `d = {item.removesuffix("_suffix"): item + "_suffix" for item in l}` (`removesuffix` requires Python >= 3.9)

Comment: No they are always pairs just like I showed in `my_list` and I want them matched in a dictionary

Comment: From where do you get that list? Do you create it? If the items are always in pairs, why do you even need this list? Why not just create the dict from the list of items (without the suffixes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just "ignore" the suffix elements and add them manually as values to the original items.

From **Python 3.9**, you can use the [`removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix) string method:

```py
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'sth1', 'sth2', 'sth2_suffix', 'sth1_suffix', 'name2_suffix', 'name1_suffix']

d = {item.removesuffix("_suffix"): item + "_suffix" for item in my_list}
print(d)
```

For other versions, you can [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) the list:

```py
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'sth1', 'sth2', 'sth2_suffix', 'sth1_suffix', 'name2_suffix', 'name1_suffix']
d = {}

for item in filter(lambda s: not s.endswith("_suffix"), my_list):
    d[item] = item + "_suffix"

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice your list in both directions and zip them together:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'sth1', 'sth2', 'sth2_suffix', 'sth1_suffix', 'name2_suffix', 'name1_suffix']
l = len(my_list)
print(dict(zip(my_list[:l//2],my_list[:l//2-1:-1])))
```

Output:

```
{'name1': 'name1_suffix', 'name2': 'name2_suffix', 'sth1': 'sth1_suffix', 'sth2': 'sth2_suffix'}
```

###### Edit: a more generic solution but more CPU-intensive:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'sth1', 'sth2', 'sth2_suffix', 'sth1_suffix', 'name2_suffix', 'name1_suffix']
keys=sorted([x for x in my_list if '_suffix' not in x])
values=sorted([x for x in my_list if '_suffix' in x])

print(dict(zip(keys,values)))
```

Comment: I don't think if it works because the list is big and elements are in random positions

Comment: I added a more generic solution, check it out

Comment: thanks yours worked too